# How to optomized the api query on server side Nodejs with express Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I have created a node.js rest API and I deploy the node application on the shared hosting server.

I have around 1000+ records in my mongoose collection.

The main problem I'm facing is If I run the backend on my local PC the query fetch time takes around 3 seconds per request but the code on the shared hosting takes more the 5 mins to complete the request.

I make the data from multiple mongoose collections and return an array of objects for my attendance records.

[image: That's the attandance the response record]

Like this, I'm making data from multiple mongoose collections.

```
exports.get = async function (req, res) {
  var empl = [];

  if (req.query.user_id) {
    empl = await userModel.find({ company_id: req.query.company_id, id: req.query.user_id });
  } else {
    empl = await userModel.find({ company_id: req.query.company_id });
  }
  // console.log("uesr",empl);
  var currentMonth;
  var currentYear;
  if (req.query.month) {
    currentMonth = req.query.month;
  } else {
    currentMonth = getmonth()
  }
  if (req.query.year) {
    currentYear = req.query.year;
  } else {
    currentYear = getyear();
  }
  //   console.log("month",currentMonth);
  //  console.log("year",currentYear);
  var currentYearsHoildays = [];
  var holidays = await holidaysModel.find({});
  //console.log("holidays",holidays);
  if (holidays && holidays.length > 0) {
    for (var h = 0; h < holidays.length; h++) {
      var hdate = holidays[h].date.split("/");
      //  console.log("holidays",hdate);
      //  console.log("current",currentYear);
      if (hdate[2] === currentYear.toString()) {
        //console.log("currendddddt",currentYear);
        var bb = {
          id: holidays[h].id,
          name: holidays[h].name,
          type: holidays[h].type,
          date: holidays[h].date,
          status: holidays[h].status,
          company_id: holidays[h].company_id,
        }
        currentYearsHoildays.push(bb);
      }

    }

  }



  var currentMonthDays = getDays(currentMonth);
  var leavesession = await leavesessionModel.find({ company_id: req.query.company_id, status:         1 });
  var users = [];
  var attandence = [];
  if (empl && empl.length > 0) {
    for (var u = 0; u < empl.length; u++) {
      var leavesession = await leavesessionModel.find({ company_id: empl[u].company_id, status: 1 });
      //console.log("leavesession: ", leavesession[0]?.id)
      let atd = [];
      let nobj = {};
      for (var i = 1; i <= currentMonthDays; i++) {
        if (i <= 9) {
          var k = '0' + i;
        } else {
          var k = i;
        }

        let date = k + '/' + currentMonth + '/' + currentYear;
        let obj = {};
        ///// holidays and leaves check 
        var holidayschk = await holidaysModel.find({ date: date });
        var leaves = await userleavesModel.find({ leavesession_id: leavesession[0]?.id, date:     date, user_id: empl[u].id });
        // console.log("sesion",leavesession[0].id);
        //console.log("leaves",leaves);
        /////

        const atten = await attandenceModel.find({ user_id: empl[u].id, date: date })
        if (atten && atten.length > 0 && atten[0].timein) {
          var pr = true;
          if (atten[0]?.totalhours == 'NaN') {
            pr = false;
          }
          obj = {
            id: atten[0]?.id,
            timein: atten[0]?.timein,
            timeout: atten[0]?.timeout,
                totalhours: atten[0]?.totalhours,
            date: date,
            present: pr,
            holiday: (holidayschk && holidayschk.length > 0) ? true : false,
            leave: (leaves && leaves.length > 0) ? true : false,
          }

        }
        // else if(holidayschk && holidayschk.length>0)
        // {
        //   obj ={

        //     timein:holidayschk[0]?.name,
        //     timeout:holidayschk[0]?.name,
        //     date:date,
        //     present:false,
        //     holiday:true
        //    }
        // }
        else {
          obj = {
            id: atten[0]?.timein,
            date: date,
            present: false,
            holiday: (holidayschk && holidayschk.length > 0) ? true : false,
            leave: (leaves && leaves.length > 0) ? true : false,
            timein: '-',
            timeout: '-',
            totalhours: 'NaN',
          }
        }
        atd.push(obj);
      }

      nobj = {
        id: empl[u].id,
        name: empl[u].first_name + " " + empl[u].last_name,
        image: empl[u].image,
        wrokfrom_home: empl[u].wrokfrom_home,
        attandence: atd,


      }
      attandence.push(nobj);
    }

    //console.log("atandence ",attandence);


  }
  //return res.json(attandence);

  const newobj = {
    Good: true,
    data: {
      holidays: currentYearsHoildays,
      attandence: attandence
    },
  };
  // console.log("OBJedt ",newobj);
  res.send(newobj);
};
```

That's my code to get the data and you can understand what I'm doing here.

Does anyone have any idea how to optimize the API for a good response?

I tried to use pagination in the API but if I fetch 3 records only it also takes a lot of time in shared hosting. I think it's from my server-side fetching data from mongoose maybe but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use $lookup aggretation for userModel and leavesessionModel by the field company_id https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/ .
Nested loops are evil, especially with database queries. Try to get rid of them.
You call this query at loop, but you can do it only once outside.

```js
var holidayschk = await holidaysModel.find({ date: date });
```

Try to fix this at first.